# Any iPhone service to find training partners?

Tags: tennis, technology

Services such as Tinder and Hot or Not can be used to find social partners but I would like to find a service by which you can find training partners such as other tennis players, CFT people and weightlifters. Is there an iPhone app to find training partners?

Comment: This question *might* be off topic. I'm voting to leave it open for now, as you've explicitly listed some competitive sports, but if the question is also about general physical fitness it might be a better fit at [Physical Fitness SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/). However, I believe you're more likely to get a suitable answer to this question at [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), as it seems to be a perfect fit for that site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any iPhone specific service, but you could give the website tennisopolis a try.

http://tennisopolis.com/

Comment: Roger there are only three people in Helsinki-Oslo areas in Tennispolis (not popular here) -- well will try it anyway! It would be cool if there was an automatic GPS thing so people closeby could contact you to have a match. Thank you for the suggestion +1.

Answer (score 1):

[Need Sporty](http://www.needsporty.com/) [*[iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/be/app/need-sporty-find-sport-partner./id862412804?mt=8)*] and [Sports Partners](http://sportspartners.com.au/) [*[iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sports-partners/id944126091?mt=8)*] are iPhone apps that use your device's location to find and meet sport partners.

I only use Need Sporty. It's simple to use and allows you to select up to 35 sports. Sports Partners also appears to provide similar functionality.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to this app? What sports does it support? This answer is a little light on details.

Comment: Vinz Sfr, I've edited the answer to make it more concise and to include additional links. Please roll back the edit if you disagree with it.